# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PHP

Tags: php

I have  php files in My includes folder like this,
`newclass.int.php`

```
<?php
class NewClass extends ParentClass {
    }
?>
```

`parentclass.int.php`

```
<?php

class ParentClass{
    public $name = "Hey There!";
}
?>
```

and `index.php` like this

```
<?php
include 'includes/parentclass.int.php';
include 'includes/newclass.int.php';
$object = new NewClass;
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>oop php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $object->name;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but I  got following error msg when running the server
`Warning: include(includes/parentclass.int.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\index.php on line 2`

`Warning: include(includes/newclass.int.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\index.php on line 3`

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NewClass' not found in C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\index.php on line 4`

`Error: Class 'NewClass' not found in C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\index.php on line 4`

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you positively sure that your file is `C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\includes\parentclass.int.php`?

Comment: yes of course..

Comment: No any idea about this matter?

Comment: not sure about how Windows handles permissions... is your `includes` directory accesible (readable/executable) by Apache?

Answer (score 0):

The given error is shown because the file you are trying to include at line **2** doesn't exist under the specified path.

Make sure **parentclass.int.php** is situated in this path: C:\wamp64\www\ooptest\includes\